# How does ob_get_contents work in Php?

Tags: php, ob-get-contents

This is a sample code from the book I am reading:

```
ob_start();
include("{$path}.ini");
$string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$pairs = parse_ini_string($string);
```

My question is, how does `ob_get_contents()` know what to get contents from? ({$path}.ini in this situation)?

Comment: Look at this :http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

Comment: @OneManCrew I have already, but I could not find any useful information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ob_get_contents` simply gets the contents of the output buffer since you called `ob_start()`. Essentially, an output buffer in PHP catches anything that would have been *output* to the browser (excluding headers). It's useful in cases where you may need to filter some output, or you're using a PHP method (such as `var_dump`) that writes output directly to screen, and you would instead like the return value of the method in a string.

In this case, because you're `include()`ing the `.ini` file, it's contents will be essentially output to screen, and `ob_get_contents()` will get the content of the file.

If you were to put `echo "I'm a little teapot short and stout";` underneath the `include`, this would also be included in `$string` after the body of the `.ini` file.

In your specific case, however, output buffering is an unnecessary overhead, simply use `file_get_contents` on the `.ini` file. I'm not sure why a book would even have this code in it at all.

Comment: Just a quick question, when you say "because you're include()ing the .ini file, it's contents will be essentially output to screen", but I do not see that contents of the path.ini on the screen?

Comment: ... because you're using output buffering, that's kindof the point. `ob_end_clean()` removes the contents of the output buffer (which are now in `$string`), and it will never be output to the screen unless you `echo $string;`.

Comment: @KorayTugay When you remove ob_start() function, you will see it on the screen.

Comment: @Burgos Thanks, I was able to see after I remove ob_end_clean(); not ob_start()... Strange..

Comment: Because `ob_start()` only begins the capture, if you don't clear (with `ob_end_clean()`) the buffer, it will be flushed to your screen at the end of the script.

Answer (score 6):

The "ob" stands for "output buffer".  When you call `ob_start()`, PHP reroutes all output (using `echo`, etc) to the output buffer.  Then you can use the other `ob_*` functions to retrieve and/or clear the buffer contents.

In your example, it will buffer any output generated by the file referenced by `"{$path}.ini"`.  When you include it, its output is added to the buffer, and when you call `ob_get_contents()`, it retrieves the contents of the buffer.

Answer (score 4):

From PHP:

```
ob_start — Turn on output buffering
ob_get_contents — Return the contents of the output buffer
ob_end_clean — Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
```

Now, ob_get_contents can collect all buffer that outputted.

[1] http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: What is included in "buffer that outputted?"

Comment: The output is not printed out instead it saved in internal buffer, then, php can collect this output and save it in string

Answer (score 2):

`ob_get_contents()` is getting everything that is echoed after calling `ob_start()` function, so there is not anything special about `{$path}.ini` - you are required to echo data you want to collect (yes, even outputs of simple `echo` or `print_r` calls will be collected - sometimes useful for debugging simple scripts).

You may understand `ob_start()` function as a simple redirection from screen to (invisible) PHP internal buffer which is later read by `ob_get_contents()`. So you will be able to redirect anything that you may see on the screen without calling `ob_start()` function (even the whole web pages).

Comment: but {$path}.ini is never echoed?

Comment: @KorayTugay The contents of it are, you called `include`.

Comment: @RudiVisser Besides echo, print_r, and include, what else is considered echoed?

Comment: @KorayTugay anything you can see in the browser without calling `ob_start()` function. You may understand it as a simple redirection data from screen to some container.